# Symfony2 - Retrieve current user as non proxy object

Tags: php, symfony

I have an issue with not being able to use my $user object (fetched via the security.context) within a doctrine call.

Code:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

$categories = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()
              ->getRepository('ToolkitBundle:Frontend\Category')
              ->findBy(array('company' => $user->getCompany()));
```

So, this ideally would get the current users info (company id, joined from another table) and filter the categories based on which company they are assigned to.

E.g User Dave is assigned to Company A. Categories B, D, and F and assigned to Company A, so thats what Dave should see.

However, I get this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies\ToolkitBundleEntityUserCompanyProxy could not be converted to string in /Sites/lwv.com/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php line 1083

I did some digging and it seems the $user object in this case isn;t a real object, but a proxy? And i believe that is causing the problem.

How can I retrieve the current user as a real object? Or, how can I use the proxy object with Doctrine?

Comment: Hmm, false alarm. Just had to do $user->getCompany()->getId() !!!!